# Bump Up hover effect on Div with css and html only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a hover effect on a div so that the div containing the image moves up on hover. I want the "polaroid" div to move up on hover. This effect works if i just apply the hover class to the img but not the whole div. Please help. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/txgvh/)

Markup:

```
<div id="home-gal-col"> <span class="span-homegal">
    <a href="/listings/category/accessories/">
        <div class="polaroid">
            <img src="/images/homegal/picture.jpg">
            <p>picture</p>
            </img>
        </div>
    </a>
   </span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#home-gal-col {
width:15%;
float:left;
padding:5px;
}

.polaroid {
border: 10px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
}

.polaroid img {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

.polaroid p {
text-align: center;
color: #D51386;
}

.span-homegal a {
-webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}

.span-homegal a:hover {
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.polaroid:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;    
}
```

You can also add the CSS 3 animation by adding the `transition` properties on the `.polaoid` class:

```css
.polaroid {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
        
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/txgvh/2/

Comment: Just note that the animation effect won't work in Internet Explorer 9 or lower as well as some other browsers which doesn't support CSS 3.